# Find Min/max for X and Y, then interpolate for 5000 txt files with python

Tags: python

I have this working code to process a single file:

```
import pandas as pd
import pygmt

#import table
df = pd.read_table("file1.txt", sep=" ", names=['X', 'Y', 'Z'] ) 

#min/max
Xmin = df['X'].min()
Xmax = df['X'].max()
Ymin = df['Y'].min()
Ymax = df['Y'].max()
#print(Xmin, Xmax)
#print(Ymin, Ymax)

#gridding with pyGMT
grid = pygmt.surface(data=df, spacing=1, region=[Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax]) 

#print(grid) 
#export
grid.to_netcdf('file1.nc')
```

Now I want to repeat this code for all *.txt files in a directory. How can I do that? I tried writing a loop like:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
```

But how can I make the respective input (*.txt) and output (*.nc) have the same name?

Comment: "But how do i manage that the respective input (.txt). and output (.nc) have the same name?" - **what exactly does this mean**? Think carefully, step by step, about what need to happen. **When you tried using** your loop (`for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):`), **what values** did you see for `file` inside the loop? That tells you the name of the input file, right? **What steps need to be taken** in order to compute the output file name? If you know how to do those steps, is there still a problem beyond that?

Comment: As an aside, please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Please do not tell us in the question about your level of experience or the overall context of your project (any more than is **required to understand the question**), and do not sign the question or offer thanks. **Just ask the question, please**. I have edited to show what it should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before in comment section you also can do it by iterating all .txt filenames and changes their formats to .nc with saving names.

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd
import pygmt

filenames_in = glob.glob("*.txt")

for filename_in in filenames_in:
    filename_out = filename_in.replace('.txt', '.nc')
    # YOUR CODE
    # import table
    df = pd.read_table(filename_in, sep=" ", names=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

    # min/max
    Xmin = df['X'].min()
    Xmax = df['X'].max()
    Ymin = df['Y'].min()
    Ymax = df['Y'].max()
    # print(Xmin, Xmax)
    # print(Ymin, Ymax)

    # gridding with pyGMT
    grid = pygmt.surface(data=df, spacing=1, region=[Xmin, Xmax, Ymin, Ymax])

    # print(grid)
    # export
    grid.to_netcdf(filename_out)
```